# Updating changeLog file after changing table

Tags: mysql, liquibase, changelog

I have a database (test) and a table (example). Example has attributes id(int), name(varchar). Then I decide to generate the changeLog file using liquibase. Now if I decide to add a new attribute age(int) to the table. What command do I need to use in the command prompt in order to add the changeSet to the changeLog file?

Answer (score 1):

The way liquibase works is that you create the changeSet yourself (e.g. in xml) and then let liquibase create your database (tables, etc).

The generation of the changelog from an existing database is mainly intended to be used as a starting point when you want to get started with liquibase while you already have an existing database.

You can of course run the generateChangelog command again and have a new changelog file that will include you new attribute and replace the changelog file you got from the first run.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the database 'manually' (using whatever tools the database provider makes available, etc.) you can then use the Liquibase `diffchangeLog` command to append a changeset to your changelog. You should probably inspect the changelog afterwards to ensure it is going to do what you expect. To let Liquibase know that the database you manually changed already has the change described in the changelog, you can run the Liquibase `changeLogSync` command.